# Link from one page to drop down in page two

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, hotlinking

I'm trying to create an `<a>` link in html page 1 that takes the user to html page 2.  After html page 2 loads, I want a drop down function to execute. Essentially it is a link from html page 1 to drop down in html2.

I am not very good with javascript, but I've tried anything I could find so far and nothing works. The link between the pages works, but I cannot get the drop down function to execute on load of html page 2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

HTML Page 1

```
<a class="link2index" href="index2.html#test" onclick ="f();return false;">Read more about technology hubs in South Africa</a>
<script>
function f(){
testwindow = window.load("index2.html#test"); //this is working to load but not to load the dropdown

//testwindow.addEventListener('click', myFunction38()); not working
//window.onload = myFunction38 ()

//testwindow.addEventListener('load', myFunction38()){
//document.getElementById("myDropdown38").classList.toggle("show");}; not working


//window.open('index2.html');
//window.somefunction = myFunction38(){
//document.getElementById("myDropdown38").classList.toggle("show");} not working
}
</script>
```

HTML Page 2 to where I'm targeting

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button id="test" onclick="myFunction38()" class="dropbtn">Cape Town</button>
<div id="myDropdown38" class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">
  <img src="media/capetown.jpg" alt="South Africa">
  Cape Town-based Labsorganises digital and entrepreneurship bootcamps, and provides an investment of up to $20,000 for every social enterprise developed through their program. 
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction38() {
   document.getElementById("myDropdown38").classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for us to understand what your issue is, please post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use the window.onload function to run some JavaScript to dynamically add html to your body and show a "drop-down".

But since html2 can be reached in other ways(like bookmark or copy/paste into browser) and not just through hyperlink inside html1, you could also append some query string or fragment in html2 when it is loaded from html1 (append it to the href of `a` tag). Inside the onload function you can then check if the same exists and decide whether or not to show drop-down.

I will not be giving a code since the functionality is vaguely defined in the question. But this should help you solve it on your own.